# Syntax error using form field in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, forms, syntax, sinatra, erb

I keep getting the following syntax error in my index.html.erb file. I'm using Ruby 2.1.2. and Sinatra 1.4.5. Any comments are appreciated.

```
syntax error, unexpected ')' @_out_buf = ''; @_out_buf.concat(( form_for(@user) do |f| ).to_s)

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up"%></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `form_for` is a Rails helper, it's not present in sinatra by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a block in an ERB template like you do with your `form_for` call, you can't use the `<%=` tag here. While this is required in Rails, it is only because they [patch ERB](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.8/actionview/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb#L38-L56) in a rather horribly way to implement this.

If you do not use Rails, you have to use this:

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, unless you use an external library to implement this, note that `form_for` is not available in standard Sinatra.